# How can one collect the terms of same power of a variable in a big expression?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

In the expression `A[x]` below, I find it hard with `Collect[]` to get the terms of the same power of  `x` together. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
    A[x_]:={{(0.000127157 (6.425*10^-6 - 0.000146567 x + 0.00508896 x^2 - 
        0.0564303 x^3 + 0.296598 x^4 - 1.0151 x^5 + 2.44505 x^6 - 
        3.57259 x^7 + 3.53854 x^8 + 2.78045 x^9 - 4.51316 x^10 + 
        13.0748 x^11 + 1. x^12)^2)/(x^2 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
        0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 + 
        x^6)^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 0.0000617314 x^2 - 
        0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 0.0186077 x^5 + 
        0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 
        1.47228 x^10 - 1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
        1. x^14)) + (0.000127157 (0.0000242938 - 0.000554191 x + 
        0.00750518 x^2 - 0.063329 x^3 + 0.356771 x^4 - 1.50927 x^5 + 
        4.80304 x^6 - 11.3351 x^7 + 21.1886 x^8 - 27.0995 x^9 + 
        26.3564 x^10 - 13.0358 x^11 - 1. x^12)^2)/(x^2 (0.00301401 - 
        0.0343778 x + 0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 
        0.8 x^5 + x^6)^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
        0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
        0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 0.448064 x^8 - 
        0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 
        1.6 x^13 + 1. x^14)) + 
   1/2 (0. + ((-4.81614*10^-10 + 2.92309*10^-8 x - 
           6.91645*10^-7 x^2 + 0.0000110376 x^3 - 0.000114545 x^4 + 
           0.000789897 x^5 - 0.00398868 x^6 + 0.0159288 x^7 - 
           0.0513992 x^8 + 0.137134 x^9 - 0.307216 x^10 + 
           0.568609 x^11 - 0.894569 x^12 + 1.10848 x^13 - 
           1.16436 x^14 + 0.800628 x^15 - 
           0.46875 x^16) (0. - (0.0520833 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
                0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 +
                 x^6) (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
                0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
                0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 
                0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 
                1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
                1. x^14) (1.02744*10^-9 - 6.23593*10^-8 x + 
                1.47551*10^-6 x^2 - 0.0000235469 x^3 + 
                0.000244363 x^4 - 0.00168511 x^5 + 0.00850918 x^6 - 
                0.0339814 x^7 + 0.109652 x^8 - 0.292552 x^9 + 
                0.655394 x^10 - 1.21303 x^11 + 1.90841 x^12 - 
                2.36477 x^13 + 2.48396 x^14 - 1.70801 x^15 + 
                1. x^16))/(x^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
                0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
                0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 
                0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 
                1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
                1. x^14) (-2.53752*10^-10 + 6.78734*10^-9 x - 
                1.02087*10^-7 x^2 + 1.05917*10^-6 x^3 - 
                8.26377*10^-6 x^4 + 0.0000516886 x^5 - 
                0.000269921 x^6 + 0.00120863 x^7 - 0.00472967 x^8 + 
                0.0163866 x^9 - 0.0507427 x^10 + 0.141377 x^11 - 
                0.355936 x^12 + 0.812161 x^13 - 1.68078 x^14 + 
                3.15558 x^15 - 5.3607 x^16 + 8.22001 x^17 - 
                11.2979 x^18 + 13.8367 x^19 - 14.8751 x^20 + 
                13.8743 x^21 - 10.8366 x^22 + 6.91886 x^23 - 
                3.2 x^24 + 1. x^25))))/(x^3 (0.00301401 - 
           0.0343778 x + 0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 
           0.8 x^5 + x^6)^3) + ((-4.81614*10^-10 + 2.92309*10^-8 x - 
           6.91645*10^-7 x^2 + 0.0000110376 x^3 - 0.000114545 x^4 + 
           0.000789897 x^5 - 0.00398868 x^6 + 0.0159288 x^7 - 
           0.0513992 x^8 + 0.137134 x^9 - 0.307216 x^10 + 
           0.568609 x^11 - 0.894569 x^12 + 1.10848 x^13 - 
           1.16436 x^14 + 0.800628 x^15 - 
           0.46875 x^16) (0. - (0.0520833 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
                0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 +
                 x^6) (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
                0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
                0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 
                0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 
                1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
                1. x^14) (1.02744*10^-9 - 6.23593*10^-8 x + 
                1.47551*10^-6 x^2 - 0.0000235469 x^3 + 
                0.000244363 x^4 - 0.00168511 x^5 + 0.00850918 x^6 - 
                0.0339814 x^7 + 0.109652 x^8 - 0.292552 x^9 + 
                0.655394 x^10 - 1.21303 x^11 + 1.90841 x^12 - 
                2.36477 x^13 + 2.48396 x^14 - 1.70801 x^15 + 
                1. x^16))/(x^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
                0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
                0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 
                0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 
                1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
                1. x^14) (-2.53752*10^-10 + 6.78734*10^-9 x - 
                1.02087*10^-7 x^2 + 1.05917*10^-6 x^3 - 
                8.26377*10^-6 x^4 + 0.0000516886 x^5 - 
                0.000269921 x^6 + 0.00120863 x^7 - 0.00472967 x^8 + 
                0.0163866 x^9 - 0.0507427 x^10 + 0.141377 x^11 - 
                0.355936 x^12 + 0.812161 x^13 - 1.68078 x^14 + 
                3.15558 x^15 - 5.3607 x^16 + 8.22001 x^17 - 
                11.2979 x^18 + 13.8367 x^19 - 14.8751 x^20 + 
                13.8743 x^21 - 10.8366 x^22 + 6.91886 x^23 - 
                3.2 x^24 + 1. x^25))))/(x^3 (0.00301401 - 
           0.0343778 x + 0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 
           0.8 x^5 + x^6)^3))}}
```

$\textbf{EDIT}:$ Thanks to @DanielLichtblau and @Bill. After trying `g[x_] = Series[A[x], {x, 0, 10}]` I get the following otuput:

$\left\{-\frac{0.0000111804}{x^5}+\frac{0.000803058}{x^4}-\frac{0.0196812}{x^3}+\frac{0.59498}{x^2}+\frac{14.8958}{x}+710.252+20289. x+298784. x^2-8.62929\times 10^6 x^3-9.2835\times 10^8 x^4-4.5384\times 10^{10} x^5-1.54194\times 10^{12} x^6-3.39047\times 10^{13} x^7-1.9156\times 10^{13} x^8+4.40953\times 10^{16} x^9+2.72807\times 10^{18} x^{10}+O\left(x^{11}\right)\right\}$

But now when I want `g[something]` the result is indeterminate!

The reason I gave the output in *latex* format is the when I copied the copy the cell content in the  usual way, it looks weird as below:

```
  {
SeriesData[
 x, 0, {-0.000011180389420975474`, 
  0.0008030579122147957, -0.01968121153014745, 0.5949799465416155, 
  14.895777584273427`, 710.2517058742889, 20289.03186220849, 
  298783.9150682995, -8.629290098421948*^6, -9.28350091986216*^8, \
-4.538400882595996*^10, -1.5419393803736648`*^12, \
-3.390474642132826*^13, -1.9156007287082703`*^13, 
  4.409525047780573*^16, 2.7280735758900367`*^18}, -5, 11, 1]}
```

Comment: Collect is for polynomials and this appears to be a rational function in the variable given. Would Series work for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks, @DanielLichtblau for telling about Series[]. I tried g[x_] = Series[A[x], {x, 0, 10}] and it gives a nice series, but the problem is that g[x] turns out to be Indeterminate for all values I checked. I do not under why!

Comment: Thanks, @Bill. I think Daniel Lichtblau suggested Series works for me as it gives a nice series expansion. But for some strange reason,  when I put some value of x into the series, it shows Indeterminate!

Comment: Plugging in a value gives a very clear error message. To avoid that pitfall, use say `Normal[Series[A[x],{x,0,10}]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

A[x_] = {{(0.000127157 (6.425*10^-6 - 0.000146567 x + 0.00508896 x^2 - 
             0.0564303 x^3 + 0.296598 x^4 - 1.0151 x^5 + 2.44505 x^6 - 
             3.57259 x^7 + 3.53854 x^8 + 2.78045 x^9 - 4.51316 x^10 + 
             13.0748 x^11 + 1. x^12)^2)/(x^2 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
             0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 + 
             x^6)^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 0.0000617314 x^2 - 
            0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 0.0186077 x^5 + 
            0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 
            1.47228 x^10 - 1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
            1. x^14)) + (0.000127157 (0.0000242938 - 0.000554191 x + 
             0.00750518 x^2 - 0.063329 x^3 + 0.356771 x^4 - 1.50927 x^5 + 
             4.80304 x^6 - 11.3351 x^7 + 21.1886 x^8 - 27.0995 x^9 + 
             26.3564 x^10 - 13.0358 x^11 - 1. x^12)^2)/(x^2 (0.00301401 - 
             0.0343778 x + 0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 
             0.8 x^5 + x^6)^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
            0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
            0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 0.448064 x^8 - 
            0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 
            1.6 x^13 + 1. x^14)) + 
       1/2 (0. + ((-4.81614*10^-10 + 2.92309*10^-8 x - 6.91645*10^-7 x^2 + 
               0.0000110376 x^3 - 0.000114545 x^4 + 0.000789897 x^5 - 
               0.00398868 x^6 + 0.0159288 x^7 - 0.0513992 x^8 + 
               0.137134 x^9 - 0.307216 x^10 + 0.568609 x^11 - 0.894569 x^12 + 
               1.10848 x^13 - 1.16436 x^14 + 0.800628 x^15 - 
               0.46875 x^16) (0. - (0.0520833 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
                    0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 + 
                    x^6) (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 0.0000617314 x^2 - 
                    0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 0.0186077 x^5 + 
                    0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 0.448064 x^8 - 
                    0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 1.9312 x^11 + 
                    2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 1. x^14) (1.02744*10^-9 - 
                    6.23593*10^-8 x + 1.47551*10^-6 x^2 - 0.0000235469 x^3 + 
                    0.000244363 x^4 - 0.00168511 x^5 + 0.00850918 x^6 - 
                    0.0339814 x^7 + 0.109652 x^8 - 0.292552 x^9 + 
                    0.655394 x^10 - 1.21303 x^11 + 1.90841 x^12 - 
                    2.36477 x^13 + 2.48396 x^14 - 1.70801 x^15 + 
                    1. x^16))/(x^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
                    0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
                    0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 
                    0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 
                    1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
                    1. x^14) (-2.53752*10^-10 + 6.78734*10^-9 x - 
                    1.02087*10^-7 x^2 + 1.05917*10^-6 x^3 - 
                    8.26377*10^-6 x^4 + 0.0000516886 x^5 - 0.000269921 x^6 + 
                    0.00120863 x^7 - 0.00472967 x^8 + 0.0163866 x^9 - 
                    0.0507427 x^10 + 0.141377 x^11 - 0.355936 x^12 + 
                    0.812161 x^13 - 1.68078 x^14 + 3.15558 x^15 - 
                    5.3607 x^16 + 8.22001 x^17 - 11.2979 x^18 + 
                    13.8367 x^19 - 14.8751 x^20 + 13.8743 x^21 - 
                    10.8366 x^22 + 6.91886 x^23 - 3.2 x^24 + 
                    1. x^25))))/(x^3 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
                0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 + 
                x^6)^3) + ((-4.81614*10^-10 + 2.92309*10^-8 x - 
               6.91645*10^-7 x^2 + 0.0000110376 x^3 - 0.000114545 x^4 + 
               0.000789897 x^5 - 0.00398868 x^6 + 0.0159288 x^7 - 
               0.0513992 x^8 + 0.137134 x^9 - 0.307216 x^10 + 0.568609 x^11 - 
               0.894569 x^12 + 1.10848 x^13 - 1.16436 x^14 + 0.800628 x^15 - 
               0.46875 x^16) (0. - (0.0520833 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
                    0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 + 
                    x^6) (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 0.0000617314 x^2 - 
                    0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 0.0186077 x^5 + 
                    0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 0.448064 x^8 - 
                    0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 1.9312 x^11 + 
                    2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 1. x^14) (1.02744*10^-9 - 
                    6.23593*10^-8 x + 1.47551*10^-6 x^2 - 0.0000235469 x^3 + 
                    0.000244363 x^4 - 0.00168511 x^5 + 0.00850918 x^6 - 
                    0.0339814 x^7 + 0.109652 x^8 - 0.292552 x^9 + 
                    0.655394 x^10 - 1.21303 x^11 + 1.90841 x^12 - 
                    2.36477 x^13 + 2.48396 x^14 - 1.70801 x^15 + 
                    1. x^16))/(x^2 (2.6632*10^-8 - 2.01772*10^-6 x + 
                    0.0000617314 x^2 - 0.000682589 x^3 + 0.00416839 x^4 - 
                    0.0186077 x^5 + 0.0658926 x^6 - 0.186156 x^7 + 
                    0.448064 x^8 - 0.872995 x^9 + 1.47228 x^10 - 
                    1.9312 x^11 + 2.17943 x^12 - 1.6 x^13 + 
                    1. x^14) (-2.53752*10^-10 + 6.78734*10^-9 x - 
                    1.02087*10^-7 x^2 + 1.05917*10^-6 x^3 - 
                    8.26377*10^-6 x^4 + 0.0000516886 x^5 - 0.000269921 x^6 + 
                    0.00120863 x^7 - 0.00472967 x^8 + 0.0163866 x^9 - 
                    0.0507427 x^10 + 0.141377 x^11 - 0.355936 x^12 + 
                    0.812161 x^13 - 1.68078 x^14 + 3.15558 x^15 - 
                    5.3607 x^16 + 8.22001 x^17 - 11.2979 x^18 + 
                    13.8367 x^19 - 14.8751 x^20 + 13.8743 x^21 - 
                    10.8366 x^22 + 6.91886 x^23 - 3.2 x^24 + 
                    1. x^25))))/(x^3 (0.00301401 - 0.0343778 x + 
                0.140516 x^2 - 0.349829 x^3 + 0.769716 x^4 - 0.8 x^5 + 
                x^6)^3))}} // Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify;

Dimensions@A[x]

(* {1, 1} *)
```

This is a matrix with only one element. What is the purpose of the List brackets?

```
g[x_] = Series[A[x][[1, 1]], {x, 0, 10}] // Normal;

Plot[g[x], {x, -1/20, 1/20},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

```
root = SolveValues[g[x] == 0, x, Reals]
```

[image]

```
root[[1]] // N

(* 0.0150744 *)

g[root[[1]]] // Simplify

(* 0 *)
```